# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi} e^{-t} t^{-x} d t d x=e+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-t}}{\pi^{2}+\log ^{2}(t)} d t$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Here's the story: I've been trying, without any success, for days now to derive the difference formula for the Fransén-Robinson constant. I was able to resolve one part, but then the equality up there is what is stopping me right now, from finishing off the calculations. I would highly appreciate some help. As of right now, I tried using Laplace transforms and Fubini to solve it, but the factor of $+e$ is always missing. I suppose it has to do with convergence issues.

Comment: Also, I tried finding at least some numerical approximation, if said equality is even true. Sadly WA couldn't compute the double integral, so it would be worth checking, if said statement even holds!

Comment: Integral $\int_0^1 e^{-t}t^{-x}dt$ seems to diverge unless $x<1$. When you consider the scaling factor $\sin(\pi x)/\pi$, you get $0$'s for integer values of $x$ as well, but the LHS definitely looks ill-defined.

Comment: Ahhhh damn, I thought so :/ It seems to me, that the integral definition of the gamma fct. won't work here :/

Comment: Also, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi} e^{-t} t^{-x}d x=\frac{e^{-t}}{\pi^{2}+\log ^{2}(t)}$, but for $t>1$, according to [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSin%5B%5C%5BPi%5D+x%5D%2F%5C%5BPi%5D+E%5E-t+t%5E-x,+%7Bx,+0,+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that there is a typo in the double integral, $dtdx$ instead of $dxdt$ because if not the double integral will not be convergent. So, the presumed relationship might be :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi} e^{-t} t^{-x} d x d t \color{red}{\stackrel{?}{=}} e+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-t}}{\pi^{2}+\log ^{2}(t)} d t \tag 1$$

$\int_{0}^{1} \sin (\pi x) t^{-x} dx =\pi\frac{t+1}{t}\frac{1}{\ln^2(t)+\pi^2}$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi} e^{-t} t^{-x} d x d t = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t+1}{t}\frac{e^{-t}}{\pi^{2}+\log ^{2}(t)} d t$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi} e^{-t} t^{-x} d x d t = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t(\pi^{2}+\log ^{2}(t))} d t + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\pi^{2}+\log ^{2}(t)} d t$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi} e^{-t} t^{-x} d x d t \simeq 0.451747+0.089488 \simeq 0.541235$$
This is far from 
$$e+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-t}}{\pi^{2}+\log ^{2}(t)} d t \simeq 2.718282+0.053992\simeq2.772274 $$

Thus Eq.$(1)$ isn't correct. One cannot say why without checking the previous calculus which lead to this equation.

Moreover the original typing $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi} e^{-t} t^{-x} d t d x $ is obviously not correct because not convergent for $x\geq 1$ and $t\to 0$.